# Find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ by integrating over a semicircle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to find
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$ by solving $$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the upper semi-circle, with appropriate choices for the paths.

My issue is bounding the outer path, say $\Gamma_{1}$, where $$\Gamma_{1}(\theta)=Re^{i\theta},\hspace{20pt}0\leq\theta\leq \pi.$$

The text I'm following along with is Greene & Krantz. They decide to split $\Gamma_{1}$ up into two pieces, one where $\text{Im}(\Gamma_{1})<\sqrt{R}$ and $\text{Re}(\Gamma_{1})\geq \sqrt{R}.$ After this, they just say how it is bounded. I'm not sure how they get their bound.

Edit: Just in case someone else working through Green & Krantz's text runs into this same issue, it appears to be the case that they obtain their bound on the outer part of the semi-circle by, in fact, using a square. It seems to me to be more efficient to use a square in the first place than using a circle and then bounding the circle by a square. Seeing as they never discuss Jordan's inequality, this seems to be the most appropriate answer.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the text to which you refer, but I'm guessing that it must discuss Jordan's inequality at some point, and its relevance to such bounds.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not mention Jordan's inequality at all. I'm not sure how to approach this without it.